# how to circumvent Kotlin's restriction "Type parameter is forbidden for catch parameter"

Tags: generics, exception, kotlin

I have defined the following function:

```
inline fun <T> T.tryTo(block: T.() -> Unit): T? {
    try {
        block()
    } catch (ex: IllegalArgumentException) {
        return this
    }
    return null
}
```

The purpose is to build a chain of try-actions on an object, e.g.:

```
val input: String = getInput();

input.tryTo /* treat as a file name and open the file */ {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(File(this))
}?.tryTo /* treat as a number */ {
    try {
        doSomethingWithTheNumber(parseInt(this))
    } catch (ex: NumberFormatException) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException()
    }
}?.tryTo {
    println("All options tried, none worked out. Don't know how to treat this input.")
}
```

So far that works fine.

But, as you can see in the middle *tryTo*-block ("treat as a number"), it is inconvenient to rethrow an "expected" exception as an IllegalArgumentException to keep the schema working. It would be nicer to write:

```
val input: String = getInput();

input.tryTo<IllegalArgumentException> /* treat as a file name and open the file */ {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(File(this))
}?.tryTo<NumberFormatException> /* treat as a number */ {
    doSomethingWithTheNumber(parseInt(this))
}?.tryTo<Exception> {
    println("All options tried, none worked out. Don't know how to treat this input.")
}
```

So, I have rewritten the function *tryTo* to:

```
inline fun <T, X: Exception> T.tryTo(block: T.() -> Unit): T? {
    try {
        block()
    } catch (ex: X) {
        return this
    }
    return null
}
```

Unfortunately, the latter does not compile: "Type parameter is forbidden for catch parameter".

**How to circumvent this restriction?**

---

Addendum:

Now I've got it to:

```
inline fun <T, reified X: Exception> T.tryTo(block: T.() -> Unit): T? {
    try {
        block()
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        return if (ex is X) this else throw ex
    }
    return null
}
```

But I'm still not happy with this because it requires me to specify **both** types explicitly ("Type inference failed..." / "2 type arguments expected ..."):

```
input.tryTo<String, IllegalArgumentException> /* treat as a file in the stapel-directory */ {
    ...
}
```

though the first type parameter is obvious as inferable from the receiver object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I thought this would be possible if you just made the type parameter reified, but apparently it is not. I did find the [source](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1eca402332642b22fd89380b74bb5e05cb2a5bfd/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/types/expressions/ControlStructureTypingVisitor.java#L568) of this check, and it quite clearly errors for any sort of type parameter in a catch clause, whether it's reified or not.

The commit message that added these checks references [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8320) - apparently the catch clause with a type parameter was catching all thrown `Exception` instances, and crashing with a `ClassCastException` if the exception wasn't of the specified type.

A possible workaround for your case comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3024672/4465208) for the similar Java question - if the generic type is reified, you can check if the exception thrown was of that specific type, which I believe makes this function what you're looking for:

```
inline fun <T, reified X : Exception> T.tryTo(block: T.() -> Unit): T? {
    try {
        block()
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        if (ex is X) {
            return this
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

Although the call site gets quite ugly because you can't just specify the second type parameter of a function call if it has two type parameters:

```
val input: String = getInput()

input.tryTo<String, IllegalArgumentException> /* treat as a file name and open the file */ {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(File(this))
}?.tryTo<String, NumberFormatException> /* treat as a number */ {
    doSomethingWithTheNumber(parseInt(this))
}?.tryTo<String, Exception> {
    println("All options tried, none worked out. Don't know how to treat this input.")
}
```

---

A slightly nicer alternative to the above, and closer to the original Java answer:

```
inline fun <T> T.tryTo(exceptionType: KClass<out Exception>, block: T.() -> Unit): T? {
    try {
        block()
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        if (exceptionType.isInstance(ex)) {
            return this
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

With the `KClass` instances passed in like so:

```
input.tryTo(IllegalArgumentException::class) /* treat as a file name and open the file */ {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(File(this))
}?.tryTo(NumberFormatException::class) /* treat as a number */ {
    doSomethingWithTheNumber(parseInt(this))
}?.tryTo(Exception::class) {
    println("All options tried, none worked out. Don't know how to treat this input.")
}
```

Comment: I've played with the same variant. See my addednum 2 min ago.

Comment: Oh, okay :) I've also just edited my answer with another alternative that could work.

Comment: I've refined your solution with the default value IllegalArgumentException::class for the parameter exceptionType. The result is even better as what I've aimed at from the beginning: now in most cases I don't need to mention the exception type at all.

Comment: That's a neat solution if that's what you need in your case, glad we could solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply remove the receiver parameter

and it is better to use `?:` then `?.` for `else` semantic

```
inline fun <reified E : Throwable> runIgnoring(block: () -> Unit): Unit? {
    return try {
        block()
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        if (e is E) null else throw e
    }
}

val input: String = getInput()

runIgnoring<IllegalArgumentException> /* treat as a file name and open the file */ {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(File(input))
} ?: runIgnoring<NumberFormatException> /* treat as a number */ {
    doSomethingWithTheNumber(parseInt(input))
} ?: run {
    println("All options tried, none worked out. Don't know how to treat this input.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inline fun <T, reified X: Exception> T.tryTo(block: T.() -> Unit): T? {
    return try {
        block()
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        when(ex) {
            is E -> this
            else null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.