# Catching exception defined by given KClass<in Exception> in Kotlin?

Tags: generics, kotlin

For example, I want to write a test which should catch a specific subclass of Exception.
For this, I write

```
fun test(klazz: KClass<in Exception>) {
    try {
        ...
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        if (!kclazz.isInstance(e)) {
            throw e
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more simple way of doing this in one line? Because I don't feel like adding an extra class check in such cases only to throw caught exception further is a good solution. Is there any way like in the code below?

```
fun test(klazz: KClass<in Exception>) {
    try {
        ...
    } catch (e: klazz(smth here)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I am almost sure there is none, because I tried many different ways. But in this case it'll be cool if someone could explain why it's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible because the grammar

```
catchBlock
(used by tryExpression)
  : 'catch' '(' annotation* simpleIdentifier ':' type ')' block
  ;
```

[requires a `type` in that position](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#catchBlock), and there's no way for a type to depend on a value like `klazz` (in Kotlin).

I tried

```
inline fun <reified E : Exception> test() {
    try {
        ...
    } catch (e: E) {
        ...
    }
}
```

but this is specifically excluded, [apparently because it didn't work properly when it wasn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49984535/9204). Of course

```
} catch (e: Exception) {
    if (e is E) ...
}
```

does work, and may be better for you than passing a `KClass`.

Comment: Thank you! Will use the last method then.

Comment: You may want to accept the answer if it answered your question fully (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar using this higher-order utility function:

```
/**
 * Asserts that the given block of code throws an exception of the specified type.
 *
 * This is much more fine-grained than `@Test(expected = ...)`, letting
 * you check that the exception was thrown by specific line(s) of code.
 *
 * @return The exception thrown.  This lets you make further tests on it
 *         (e.g. in an `also{}` block).
 * @throws AssertionError if no exception, or one of another type, was thrown.
 */
inline fun <reified T: Exception> assertThrows(exceptionClass: KClass<T> = T::class, block: () -> Unit): T {
    try {
        block()
        throw AssertionError("Should have thrown ${exceptionClass.simpleName}!")
    } catch (x: Exception) {
        if (x is T)
            return x
        throw AssertionError("Should have thrown ${exceptionClass.simpleName}, but threw $x!")
    }
}
```

You can use it in unit tests, like:

```
@Test fun myTest() {
    assertThrows(NullPointerException::class) {
        // Some code that should throw a NullPointerException...
    }
}
```

(That's more than one line, but it's still pretty concise, and reads well.)

Comment: Surely you'd prefer writing `assertThrows<NullPointerException>() { ... }`? And I am not sure why pass `exceptionClass` as a parameter if `reified` is used.

Comment: I think it was more for consistency with JUnit's other `assert…` functions.  But of course other variants are possible — I'm not claiming this is the best!