# Making the inner class of a generic class extend Throwable

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn’t Java allow generic subclasses of Throwable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501277/why-doesnt-java-allow-generic-subclasses-of-throwable)

I'm trying to make a regular RuntimeException inside a generic class like this:

```
public class SomeGenericClass<SomeType> {

    public class SomeInternalException extends RuntimeException {
        [...]
    }

    [...]
}
```

This piece of code gives me an error on the word `RuntimeException` saying `The generic class SomeGenericClass<SomeType>.SomeInternalException may not subclass java.lang.Throwable`.

What has this RuntimeException to do with my class being generic?

Comment: can you make the nested class static?

Comment: I would say not to close as duplicate, only because there are two pieces to the puzzle here, and that post only addresses one of them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Java doesn't allow generic subclasses of Throwable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/501277/130224). And, a nonstatic inner class is effectively parameterized by the type parameters of its outerclass (See [Oracle JDK Bug 5086027](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5086027)). For instance, in your example, instances of your innerclass have types of form `SomeGenericClass<T>.SomeInternalException`. So, Java doesn't allow the static inner class of a generic class to extend `Throwable`.

A workaround would be to make `SomeInternalException` a static inner class. This is because if the innerclass is `static` its type won't be generic, i.e., `SomeGenericClass.SomeInternalException`.

```
public class SomeGenericClass<SomeType> {

    public static class SomeInternalException extends RuntimeException {
        [...]
    }

    [...]
}
```

Comment: A.R.S. is right, you should say that non-static inner classes inside generic classes are themselves considered generic.