# How to restrict that subclass cannot be generic?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, compiler-construction, throwable

***Compile time error:** The generic class may not subclass java.lang.Throwable*

```
public class TestGenericClass<E> extends Exception {

/*Above line will give compile error, the generic class TestGenericClass<E> may 
  not subclass java.lang.Throwable*/

    public TestGenericClass(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

Above compile time error is for the reason given in  [§ jls-8.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2) as below, and explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501277/why-doesnt-java-allow-generic-subclasses-of-throwable):

> It is a compile-time error if a generic class is a direct or indirect subclass of Throwable(§11.1.1).
>
> *This restriction is needed since the catch mechanism of the Java Virtual Machine works only with non-generic classes.*

**Question:**

- **How** it is restricted that subclass of `java.lang.Throwable` will not be generic class?
- Or more generic question will be, how to restrict that subclasses of any class cannot be generic?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if they use an actual Java tool. This might just be a special case that they've included in the compiler.

Comment: If that is the case, then how can I create my own custom class that will not have a `Generic` class.

Comment: You cannot. This is done in the compiler. You can always extend the compiler and add in a rule for your class.

Comment: Just have your class extend the `Throwable`, if you must let the compiler complain when someone tries to do that.

Comment: @Bhesh, I suppose someone might be tempted to throw it then...

Comment: @BoristheSpider please elaborate.

Comment: @BheshGurung we extends to `Throwable` when we are creating some `Exception` or `Error` class. This will give problem if I will have to extend class like `Applet`

Comment: Please don't take that suggestion seriously. I don't think you have a very legit question here. May I ask you why you want to be able to do that?

Comment: @BheshGurung I am just curious to know how things are implemented for `java.lang.Throwable`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> How it is restricted that subclass of java.lang.Throwable will not be
>   generic class?

Here's how OpenJDK compiler performs the check:

```
import com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.*;   

private void attribClassBody(Env<AttrContext> env, ClassSymbol c) {
    ....

    // Check that a generic class doesn't extend Throwable
    if (!c.type.allparams().isEmpty() && types.isSubtype(c.type, syms.throwableType))
        log.error(tree.extending.pos(), "generic.throwable");
```

As you can see forbidden type is kind of harcoded, so you can't use the same technique for your custom class without compiler code customization.

[Full source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/tl/langtools/file/9d81ae1c417a/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/comp/Attr.java)

Comment: Can you please add class name and/or any other sources?

Comment: Although hacky, you could prevent subclasses from being generic by making your base class extend throwable :)

Comment: What occurs if one tries to run code written on a compiler that skips this check, on a standard JVM?

Comment: @hexafraction I would guess nothing different. The restriction is only so that `catch` doesn't have to support generics at compile time. (Anything generics-related is only at compile time in Java anyway.)

Comment: @hexafraction the only spec for "standard JVM" I know is Java virtual machine specification by Oracle. This spec doesn't cover use case we're talking about, so I would say for "standard JVM" the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 10):

> How it is restricted that subclass of java.lang.Throwable will not be generic class?

This was a decision to write a special case into the compiler itself. The reason why is detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501277/why-doesnt-java-allow-generic-subclasses-of-throwable?lq=1). Basically, this is to do with a type being *reifiable*. You can read about this term [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html). In short, a type is reifiable if it's type is fully available at compile time. Generic types, for example, are not reifiable, because their types are removed by type erasure. Objects appearing in a `catch` block *need* to be *reifiable*.

> Or more generic question, how to restrict that subclasses of a class cannot be generic?

**Well there's a few options..**

At present, there is no option within the normal bounds of Java to do this. It doesn't have some sort of `final` implementation that prevents genericity being applied to subclasses. The closest thing you can get to this, as explained in the comments, is to extend the compiler and add a rule specifically for your class. This solution sends shivers down my spine. Dodge it. It means that your code will only behave with *your* version of Java, and that anyone else who wants to use your code will have to install the same version.

Obviously, the other option is to extend `Throwable`, but this really isn't a good idea. It adds a whole bunch of functionality to your class, and adds a lot of new methods to the interface of your class, that you will *never* use. From an OOP point of view, you're sacrificing the integrity of your class for the benefit of having this feature.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Haha, sorry. I know you suggested this solution. As soon as I saw *"extend the compiler"*, I honestly did flinch a little. No offence intended obviously!

Comment: That wasn't really intended a serious solution. Writing compilers should be left to the compiler writers. An annotation preprocessor is fairly simple to do. Or even something like a Checkstyle rule.

Comment: These are certainly valid options!

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to delay the error until run time, you can use use reflection in the superclass constructor(s) to see if the subclass declares any type parameters.

```
public class Example {
    public static class ProhibitsGenericSubclasses {
        public ProhibitsGenericSubclasses() {
            if (getClass().getTypeParameters().length > 0)
                throw new AssertionError("ProhibitsGenericSubclasses prohibits generic subclasses (see docs)");
        }
    }

    public static class NonGenericSubclass extends ProhibitsGenericSubclasses {}
    public static class GenericSubclass<T> extends ProhibitsGenericSubclasses {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new NonGenericSubclass());
        System.out.println(new GenericSubclass<Object>());
    }
}
```

This code prints

```
Example$NonGenericSubclass@15db9742
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: ProhibitsGenericSubclasses prohibits generic subclasses (see docs)
    at Example$ProhibitsGenericSubclasses.<init>(Example.java:12)
    at Example$GenericSubclass.<init>(Example.java:17)
    at Example.main(Example.java:21)
```

If you want to prohibit type parameters of all classes in the hierarchy, not just the most-derived class, you'll need to walk up the hierarchy using `Class#getSuperclass()`.