# Is there an effective way to use generics in a throws clause?

Tags: java, generics

According to
[Cannot Create, Catch, or Throw Objects of Parameterized Types (Java Tutorials)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#cannotCatch):

> You can, however, use a type parameter in a `throws` clause:
>
> ```
> class Parser<T extends Exception> {
>     public void parse(File file) throws T {     // OK
>         // ...
>     }
> }
> ```

But why would you want to?  You can't construct `T` here.  If you inject `T` after building it outside, isn't its stack trace going to be all wrong?  Were they simply documenting a feature that happened to work regardless of it's usefulness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have

```
public class ExceptionWithPayload<T> extends Exception {
    private final T payload;
    public ExceptionWithPayload(T payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }
    public T getPayload(){
        return payload;
    }
}
```

and then in some other class, you could write

```
throw new ExceptionWithPayload<MyClass>(myObject);
```

so as to be able to pass any object you like back to the thing that catches the exception, but with type checking in the `catch` clause.

Comment: This doesn't work, it is showing a compile time error `Generic class may not extend Throwable`

Comment: That could happen if you've made your own class called `Exception`. Don't do that.

Comment: Nope, I was trying to extend RuntimeException.

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question and post your code. Link to this one if you like.

Comment: I don't think posting a separate question would help here. It would be good, if you could review and correct the answer.

Comment: The OP accepted this answer which means it worked for that person. If you're doing something different then you have a new question. I'm not going to change my answer to fit your requirement. It's correct as it is.

Comment: I am not doing something different. This answer is clearly wrong. OP accepting it at that time, doesn't mean it's correct now. I am not asking you to delete the answer , just verify it and add a comment, if it doesn't work. Checkout the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/501284/2790036

Answer (score 3):

Why not

```
class FooParser extends Parser<FooException> {
    public void parse(File file) throws FooException {
        throw new FooException("Not Supported");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can throw checked exceptions where it was not expected with the sneaky throw trick: http://rdafbn.blogspot.hu/2013/07/lomboks-sneaky-throws.html

Or without magic: http://www.mail-archive.com/javaposse@googlegroups.com/msg05984.html