# Why do I have to deal with Throwable if I invoke getCause() on an Exception

Tags: java, exception

It is designed in Java that I get a `Throwable` object if I invoke `getCause()` on an `Exception`.

I understand that `getCause()` is simply inherited from `Throwable` and I know that `Throwable` can be either an `Error` or an `Exception`, but a programmer generally should work only on the `Exception` level without dealing with `Throwable`/`Error` classes.

What was the reason in the Java exception hierarchy design to, for example, not include `getCause()` in the `Exception` class that would return an `Exception` object?

Here is an illustration of the inconvenience taken from *Java Concurrency In Practice* (Brian Goetz):

```
public class Preloader {
    private final FutureTask<ProductInfo> future =
        new FutureTask<ProductInfo>(new Callable<ProductInfo>() {
            public ProductInfo call() throws DataLoadException {
                return loadProductInfo();
            }
        });
    private final Thread thread = new Thread(future);
    public void start() { thread.start(); }
    public ProductInfo get()
        throws DataLoadException, InterruptedException {
        try {
            return future.get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            if (cause instanceof DataLoadException)
                throw (DataLoadException) cause;
            else
                throw launderThrowable(cause);
        }
    }
}
```

It is said in the book:

> ...but also because the cause of the `ExecutionException` is returned as a `Throwable`, which is inconvenient to deal with...

And in `launderThrowable()` it is dealt with rethrowing `Error` right away (because we don't want to deal with it) and returning `RuntimeException`:

```
public static RuntimeException launderThrowable(Throwable t) {
    if (t instanceof RuntimeException)
        return (RuntimeException) t;
    else if (t instanceof Error)
        throw (Error) t;
    else
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not unchecked", t);
}
```

Comment: Because the root cause could be an `Error`.

Comment: I am asking why it is designed in such a way that I have to deal with Error.

Comment: Counter-question: Why is it so important to you that it would be an `Exception`, when all the interesting methods are in `Throwable`, like `printStackTrace()` etc.?

Comment: The question is only about why do I even need to see/deal anything other than Exception. Probably I'm just missing some idea here:)

Comment: @Ruslan I don't get what's confusing to you.  `Error`s can happen anywhere, and one way of dealing with them is to wrap them in an `Exception`, which will then have an `Error` as its cause.

Comment: I'm only dreaming:-), but probably I'd like Error to be just thrown in places where it is wrapped in an Exception:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you have a type that has a few subtypes, and their behavior is really the same, it makes sense to define the methods at the parent class. Basically, what the designers are saying is: "`Throwable` can have a cause, which is also a throwable, and you can get that cause". And you can do that in both `Exception` and `Error` because they both happen to be throwables.

Now, the `Throwable` hierarchy exists since Java 1.0, and generics didn't exist there. Nowadays you might be able to have defined the behavior like this:

```
class ModernThrowable<T extends ModernThrowable<T>> {
    T getCause() {...}
}
```

And you could define `ModernException` as `extends ModernThrowable<ModernException>` and then you could get the sort of behavior that you expect.

But this design didn't exist back then, so you get a `Throwable` back, and you have to cast it. That's how things used to work and you have to keep backward compatibility.

But actually... as plausible as this may sound, **this is not true**. At least, it's not the whole truth.

It is perfectly OK to get an `Error` as the cause of an `Exception`. Take a look at [`javax.management.RuntimeErrorException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/RuntimeErrorException.html). When you are working with an agent, you might get an `Error`, which in these special circumstances, should not cause you to abort the system immediately. So you put it as the cause of this special Exception. And thus, your `getCause()` will actually return an `Error` from an `Exception`.

So if it wasn't designed like this, you would have to go through hoops - have a specialty method just for the cause of this particular exception.

Comment: `class ModernThrowable<T extends ModernThrowable<T>>` might be possible, but [that won't happen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501277/why-doesnt-java-allow-generic-subclasses-of-throwable) :D.

Comment: @Tom Well, that's another reason, I guess. :-)

Comment: This looks to be the bast answer. How can I accept it on stackoverflow?

Comment: @Ruslan - There is a checkmark near the vote counter on the left side of the answer, which you can click to accept an answer.

Answer (score 4):

`getCause` is a method defined in `Throwable`, and simply *inherited* in `Exception`. The cause of a `Throwable` is simply a `Throwable` (it could be an `Exception` or an `Error`).

IMO, having a method, say `getCauseAsException`, that just returns an `Exception` if any as the cause exception is not really useful. You could simply invoke `getCause()` and check if it's an instance of `Exception` if you're just concerned with `Exception` and not `Error`s.

Comment: I know that:-) My question is about "why such a design is chosen", not "how this design works". I updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: @Ruslan What's the point of having a method that just gets the `Throwable` cause only if it is an `Exception`? Do you have a real case for that? I edited the answer BTW.

Comment: Added a case in my question

Comment: "You could simply invoke getCause() and check if it's an instance of Exception if you're just concerned with Exception and not Errors." - I know there are ways to handle it, my question is more about why I should handle it rather than just getting an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Programmers generally work at the Exception level when they are implementing applications. But remember that the JVM, for instance, is also implemented in Java and, in this context, programmers should work at the Throwable/Error level too.

So the question of at which level in the exception hierarchy tree you should work its more of an issue of the domain of the system you're implementing, than an issue of the language design itself. So it makes perfect sense from a language design perspective to provide the getCause method in the Throwable class, which is the root of the hierarchy tree. Since the Exception class inherits this method from its superclass, it's not necessary to provide the same method with a different return type just because in some specific domains you don't/shouldn't work with Throwable instances.