# Custom Exception with generic type

Tags: java, generics, exception

I have wrapped the Exception in my java class into a custom exception. I want my custom exception to receive two parameters, one the message and second a list.

But the problem is listOfFailedRecords has to be generic.

Something like,

```
throw new MyException("Failed due to dependency", listOfFailedRecords)
```

And the MyException class would look like,

```
public class MyException<T> extends Exception {
    List<T> listOfFailedRecords;
    MyException(String message, List<T> listOfFailedRecords) {
        super(message);
        this.listOfFailedRecords = listOfFailedRecords;
    }
}
```

But the problem is Java doesn't allow generic class to extend Exception class.

What should be the approach now?
Should I pass a list of Objects to this exception as

```
List<Object> listOfFailedRecords
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: Do the failed records have anything in common which you could make in interface for? If not it might be wise to use different exception classes for higher maintainability.

Comment: *"Or is there a better way?"* - No, there isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use an interface to group the behaviour of your failed records. If there is a specific reason you can't do it, it is likely you have a problem with your design. In this case, you should make several exception classes.

Here is a good post to understand why Java doesn't allow subclasses of throwable : https://stackoverflow.com/a/501309/3425744