# Why generics cannot be used in Exception classes in Java?

Tags: java, generics

An attempt to use generics with any class that extends Throwable produces an error saying "Generic class may not extend 'java.lang.Throwable'".

Sample code:

```
public class GenericException<T> extends Exception { }  // Compilation Error
```

I am not able to understand why generics cannot be used inside classes that extend Throwable.  Could someone explain?

Comment: Please search SO for similar question first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501277/why-doesnt-java-allow-generic-subclasses-of-throwable

Comment: Did not think about searching for Throwable instead searched for Exception which did not bring up any results.

Comment: Ali, Compilation error says "Generic class may not extend 'java.lang.Throwable'".

Comment: I should have searched for the exact error message.  I was using a java 8 certification book that mentioned that "It is not possible to have generic exception classes;" So i based my search on that.  Although the book does give an example that extends Throwable, I extended Exception class instead of Throwable.  I agree with you that this is a duplicate post.  The link that @shmosel put in the post answers the question.