# How to add Generic class in Exception class handler?

Tags: java, spring-boot, oop, exception

what i want to achieve is add Generic  in my exception class which is looked like this before :

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED)
public class ResourceGeneralErrorTest extends RuntimeException {
    
    public ResourceGeneralErrorTest(String message){
        super(message);
    }

}
```

and i use it like this :

```
throw new ResourceGeneralError("Some error string " + errorTransDoMsg.toString());
```

but i only can pass string value inside this class. I want to pass Object class in this, so i try to add this :

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED)
public class ResourceGeneralErrorTest<T> extends RuntimeException {

    private T data;
    
    public ResourceGeneralErrorTest(String message){
        super(message);
    }

}
```

which is give me error when i extends the RuntimeException class, here is the error message `Generic class may not extend 'java.lang.Throwable'` how can i keep extends RuntimeException and i can pass some object into it with my String message?

Comment: You need to add your own constructor to your class which can accept extra params and then from inside that constructor, call super constructor passing message and also initialising your values.

Comment: You can't, see here https://stackoverflow.com/q/501277/1876620

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example should work, you just need to do something like this

```
public class ResourceGeneralErrorTest extends RuntimeException {

    private Object data;
    
    public ResourceGeneralErrorTest(String message , Object error){
        super(message);
        this.data = error;
    }

    public Object getData() {
          return this.data;
    }

}
```

**Edit:** I ignored that you were extending RuntimeException, you cannot do that, generic classes not allowed to extend child of Throwable classes, but you can use Object there instead of T.

Comment: i try your code but still give me this error Generic class may not extend 'java.lang.Throwable'

Comment: Sorry, ignored that you were extending RuntimeException class, instead of T Object would work, check updated answer, hope it helps.

Comment: woah, it worked, thanks code_mechanic